# Using find in order to detect a magento module

Tags: grep, files, find

At magento routes are located in `adminhtml/routes.xml` each module has a folder named `adminhtml` with a file `routes.xml` each module has its own folder. In other words I have the following file structure:

```
vendor
+ MyModule
++ etc
+++ adminhtml
++++ routes.xml
+ AnotherModule
++ etc
+++ adminhtml
++++ routes.xml
....
```

And I want to scan the `vendor` directory and look what pathes of files `route.xml` have a specific word:

```
$ find ./vendor -name adminhtml\/routes.xml -exec grep "sales" {} +
```

But I do not get any value and also I get the following warning:

```
find: warning: ‘-name’ matches against basenames only, but the given pattern contains a directory separator (‘/’), thus the expression will evaluate to false all the time.  Did you mean ‘-wholename’?
```

How I can find files located in a specific folder pattern and have specific words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `-path` instead:

```
find ./vendor -path '*/adminhtml/routes.xml' -exec grep "sales" {} +
```

(Possibly with `-type f`, it's not likely there will be a directory named `routes.xml`.)

Answer (score 0):

An approach of mine is to filter all files matching the `routes.xml` name and contain the required wotd then filter further the result of find with grep:

```
find ./vendor -name routes.xml -exec grep "sales" {} + | grep adminhtml
```

---

Then you can open the file using the IDE and edit it/analyze it further.